# Install Firefox add-on into Firefox OS Firefox browser

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-os

I have developed some Firefox add-ons (extensions) already for Desktop and Mobile Firefox, but now I can't install the add-on/extension into the browser running in Firefox OS (I'm using the Simulator add-on). Please note I don't want to create a traditional Firefox OS application, but a traditional browser extension.

I have the application ID from Fennec (aa3c5121-dab2-40e2-81ca-7ea25febc110) in install.rdf. I also tried Mobile a23983c0-fd0e-11dc-95ff-0800200c9a66, it does not work either.

Is it that the Simulator does not support add-ons?
Or do I need a different application ID?
Or is it something totally different?

My other problem is that I can't see any debug logs, like the usual dab log cat. Even about:config is not accessible from the browser.

Comment: regarding the debug output you should be able to see it using `adb logcat`

Comment: I am guessing that it would be added at the gaia level. The scope would increase to all applications. First person to figure this out is going to be a hero. The simulator is probably going to be harder to figure out than a physical device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Firefox browser that comes with Firefox OS is still an infant. It unfortunately still doesn't support add-ons and a lot of other stuff we love from Firefox and Firefox for Android.

Comment: Man this sucks, I've been trying so hard for a week to get AdBlock on it, now to read this... Bummed :(

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary support for Firefox OS add-ons has landed recently:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=923897

It's comprised of the ability to install "apps" that are Javascript and/or CSS scripts that executed in the context of a matching Web page.

The idea is similar to how Greasemonkey worked in desktop browsers.

The functionality is not yet complete, and has not been released in consumer-ready versions of Firefox OS.

Comment: Without knowing any of the details.. that doesn't sound like it's going to be able to do low level stuff that Ad-Block would require...

Comment: Now knowning some of the details this sounds exactly like a GreaseMonkey script, and I welcome it. But you could only remove Ads once they've been loaded and have already tracked you, consumed your CPU, and network traffic. Ad-Blocker's beauty is that the  computer is not performing actions that the user does not want. A crude ad-blocker could be created but what would be the point?